# C++ segfault when passing a string or stream object by reference to recursive function

Tags: c++, recursion, segmentation-fault, tail-recursion

I'm trying to serialize my huffman tree to a file, but having issue with the recursive nature of the problem. I have no trouble printing it to console using cout, but I get segmentation fault when I try to store it in a string or write to a file.

```
string putData(Node *n, string &s) {

  if (n->leaf()) {
    s << "[" << n->value() << "]";
  } else {
    s << ".";
  }

  if (n->left())
    putData(n->left(), s);

  if (n->right())
    putData(n->right(), s);

}
```

It's the same issue with an ofstream object. Actually, after the program segfaults, I check the file and its contents are proper. But why is it segfaulting at the end? How do I stop the program from segfaulting?

```
string putData(Node *n, ofstream &s) {

  s.open("huffout.txt", ios::app);

  if (n->leaf()) {
    s << "[" << n->value() << "]";
  } else {
    s << ".";
  }
  s.close()
  if (n->left())
    putData(n->left(), s);

  if (n->right())
    putData(n->right(), s);

}
```

Comment: How are you passing an `ofstream &` to something taking a `string &`?

Comment: You will probably have to put in more effort to debug this yourself.  Have you identified exactly what line the program crashes on?  Have you used gdb to inspect the variables at that point?  Could you post the simplest possible complete program that exhibits the problem?  If you go through the process of answering these questions you probably find the solution yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function is declared to return `string` but has no return statement, if anything looks at the return value that could cause a segfault.  Your compiler should have warned you about the missing return, aren't you compiling with warnings?

Also, the first code example uses a `string` but tries to append to it with `operator<<`, presumably that's just a copy'n'paste error.

Comment: Its astonishing how anyone could miss that return type. SO never fails to help me make a fool of myself. Thanks!

Comment: @user1479360, There are compiler warnings for that. Turn them on.